# Fastest way to determine last "record".. ideally in parallel... (with gaps)

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, search

I have a data-mining application that accesses a web-site to retrieve records on an individual basis [the other web-site is still run by my company but has no API's for accessing it].  I know the first record is "1" but (without human intervention) I don't know the last record.  Working sequentially through the data can take a while (e.g. 4000 records = about 45 minutes).  To improve the user experience, I'd like to quickly establish the percentage complete.

Ideally I would implement something like a binary search to determine the last record with the least pulls from the server.  I happen in to know that these records are created by humans, so if today there were a total of 4000 records, tomorrow it is likely to be in the ball park of 4000-4020 but I'd like to avoid needing to introduce the assumption to my data-gathering application because that would require some sort of administration by the users.

1. What is the quickest way of determining the "last record"
2. To complicate the issue, records deleted look identical to records not yet created!  Whilst these are VERY rare, they do happen.  I've determined a rule of FIVE sequential failures to retrieve after the last success to indicate the last record.
3. I already have a good sequential implementation, but have determined due to the cost of processing a record that it is possible/quicker to retrieve them in parallel (e.g. 8 at a time)

Is there an established pattern/algorithm for this sort of 'last index' search (with limited gaps)?  Whilst I can aggressively (to a point) make the existing application parallel (e.g. maybe 8x faster) how can I quickly determine the user-wait duration?

1. I could make the user just wait 1/8th of the time they currently do.
2. I can spend the initial effort finding the last record, then back-filling the content to complete the operation.

Implementation specific information, I'm implementing this in C# and have access to LINQ, but this is, I feel, a language independent algorithm.

**EDIT** I already have a caching mechanism for most users, but the existing data can be changed quite frequently (5%-10% per day) and thus a caching mechanism can quickly become out of date.  I want to avoid the need for a *central-cache* so all users are unaffected by these changes, additionally there are multiple projects and caching may require accessing 'web-sites' I might not even have access too or services I develop - I'd prefer this stays within the 'user domain'.  Therefore, from time to time it is necessary to do a "full update" as quickly as possible.

Comment: I don't think you have explained yourself very well here.  It sounds like you are querying another website for data and requesting 1 record at a time until you have pulled all 4000 (which isn't a huge amount).  I'd just create a local cache (in my own database) of the records and poll the website periodically through the day to get new records.  Then getting the last record becomes trivial a database will return the 4000th record in no time without any fancy algorithm.

Comment: Whilst I can pull the records and create a local cache (indeed I do already), the records can and do change.  Whilst I have a completely separate update mechanism, from time to time it is necessary to refresh all.  This is where the users suddenly get upset that queries upon the data that take 10ms suddenly take 45 minutes!

Comment: Are the records more or less static? You say that if you have 4000 records today, you'll probably have around 4000 to 4020 records tomorrow -- can you simply store the currRecIndex somewhere and start acquiring records from there, or from, say, (currRecIndex - 20)? That should give you the last record pretty quickly, no?

Comment: Whilst most of the records are static, something like 5-10% may change per day and I'd rather decouple the caching which I do separately to the "full update" that is the justification behind the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, as you said, you can use something like binary search. You're trying to find the least upper bound of valid record indices (*n*). Start at *n* = 1, and double it until you've gone past the end. *n* is now an upper bound. Now do a binary search between *n*/2 and *n* to reduce it to the *least* upper bound.

Clearly this can be adjusted to pull down 8 or more records at a time (and it sounds like that will be necessary anyway if the only way you have of finding out that you've gone off the end is to see enough adjacent null entries).

Comment: Due to the existence of gaps in the sequence, it is possible that finding the first missing record has simply chanced upon a gap.  Therefore, once the possible upper bound is found, I'd need to work forward by my maximum gap size to ensure the sequence doesn't start again.  Assuming it restarts, I need to continue looking forward, otherwise, as you say, backtracking to find the true upper bound.  How I wish the web-application developer's had implemented a "this record was deleted" page instead of the generic "no such page!".